# Execution failed for task ':library:proguardRelease'

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools, build-tools

I just updated sdk and android studio i have this problem:

```
    Error:Execution failed for task ':library:proguardRelease'.
> java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)
```

How can i solve this?

Can i go home?

Comment: `Clean-Rebuild-Sync`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, try to use `clean`.

Second, if that doesn't help, get more info about the failure. You can use the following parameters for your build command:

- `-i` will print the logs with `INFO` level
- `-d` will print the logs with `DEBUG` level
- `-s` will print the exception stack trace

e.g., running `./gradlew assemble -d -s` should give you a lot of information that can help locate the issue.

Comment: Thank you for tips. I'll try them during the weekend. Now i installed older sdk.

Comment: Actually now it's working. They updated something? But anyway i'll accept your answer. It is helpfull. thanks.